# Left-aligning authors section in an article

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, titles

I want to align the authors section of my article to the left. If there are more than one authors, each author should be aligned left in its own cell. I am using memoir's article class.

This is what I came up with:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,english,article]{memoir}

\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}
           \large \lineskip 0.5em%
           \begin{tabular}[t]{l}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{flushleft}}

\title{My Title}
\author{
    First Author\\
    first@email.com
\and
    Second Author\\
    second@email.com
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

The code above does align the first author to the left, but the second author is still centered in its own cell.

I tried using `parbox`es for each author. However, using a `parbox` inside the `author` command resulted in the following error:

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.54 }
```

What should I do to have a nice, left-aligned authors section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}%
           \large \lineskip 0.5em%
           \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\end{flushleft}}
\renewcommand*\and{%
  \end{tabular}%
  \hskip 1em \relax
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}}
\renewcommand*{\andnext}{%
  \end{tabular}\\ \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}}
```

The `\and` command is defined in the LaTeX kernel and has a `c` column. You should also use `@{}` as shown for the first author, otherwise it won't be at the left margin.

If you're going to use also `\andnext`, probably you need to redefine it as shown.

Comment: Thank you! This is _the_ solution of my problem. Where can I find the definition of the `\and` command and other basic commands anyway (not the memoir versions, but the kernel versions)?

Comment: For example `texdef -t latex and` and `texdef -t latex -c memoir andnext`; usually I say ``less $(kpsewhich latex.ltx)`` when I want to find some command.

Comment: I guess `\preauthor` is memoir-specific. It is not recognized by Beamer. Does someone know how to get the equivalent functionality in Beamer?

Comment: @Leo This is probably worth of a fresh question.

Comment: Thanks. I added it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166531/

Answer (score 1):

Introduce the authors using the cells of the `tabular` you declared:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{array}
\preauthor{\large\noindent\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{1cm}}l}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par}

\author{%
    First Author & Second Author\\
    first@email.com & second@email.com
}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can use that. But it would be better if I could stick with the memoir's `\and` and `\andnext` commands.

Comment: @Eser Aygün: then egreg's answer will do what you want.