# Left align abstract, title and authors

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, article

I would like to re-align my title, authors and abstract to the left of the document. The example in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21012/left-aligning-authors-section-in-an-article) is basically the output I want, but I do not want to use the memoir environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{lipsum}

\usepackage{todonotes} % add [disable] to switch off

\title{Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit}
\date{}
\author{%
    Author One$^{1}$, Author2$^{2}$\\
    $^{1}$Institution 1, I 1 City, I 1 Country\\
    $^{2}$Institution 1, I 1 City, I 1 Country\\
    \underline{$^{1}$mail@domain.com}\\
    \underline{$^{2}$mail2@domain.com }
}

\pagestyle{empty} % disables page numbers
\thispagestyle{empty} % single page disable page number

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\textbf{Abstract:} \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

gives me:
[image: This output]

but I would prefer it to look more like (in terms of alignment and font size - bonus):
[image: ideal]

I've tried various alignment options, but can't seem to get inside the \maketitle. Any suggestions appreciated, as I haven't done much with regards to forcing overrides on defaults. Would I use renewcommand?

I've also tried

```
\begingroup
\let\center\flushleft
\let\endcenter\endflushleft
\maketitle
\endgroup
```

but the author section is then odd looking:

[image: flushleft]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The package [titling](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) provides esseentially the functionality found in the memoir class for titles.  However in your case, it is simpler to redefine the `\maketitle` command directly.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{\@title}

  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother

\title{Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit}
\date{}
\author{%
Author One$^{1}$, Author2$^{2}$\\
$^{1}$Institution 1, I 1 City, I 1 Country\\
    $^{2}$Institution 1, I 1 City, I 1 Country\\
    \underline{$^{1}$mail@domain.com}\\
    \underline{$^{2}$mail2@domain.com }
}

\pagestyle{empty} % disables page numbers

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % single page disable page number

\noindent
\textbf{Abstract:} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

The title and author information is to be found in the commands `\@title` and `\@author`.  As these include the character `@` in their names the refinition of `\maketitle` has to be included in at `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother` group.

I have also moved your `\thispagestyle` command to after the `\begin{document}`, so that it takes affect.

You didn't specify what spacing you wanted before the title.  You can add vertical space after the `\bgroup` in the new `\maketitle` using say `\vspace*{2cm}`.

Comment: So, just to be sure I understand correctly. You are overriding the maketitle command, inside of that you create a new group, you flushleft this group, and use the @variables to use the already defined title and author. I'm a bit confused as to what makeatletter and makeatother is responsible for. Noindent removes the indentation.

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  The `\makeatletter` changes the `catcode` of `@` from a non-letter class `other` to the letter category, so it is allowed in command names.  LaTeX uses this mechanism to hide internal commands from users.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extensive, timely and helpful answer.

Comment: When trying to add `\newline` between authors this errors pop up `There's no line here to end   \maketitle`

Comment: @Misaki Works OK for me, though it would be more consistent to use `\\`.  If you still have a problem, please post a separate question including the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, as this is an old question, but for those seeking a simple solution for adding footnotes in the authors block and selectively left justifying as well as making some text smaller, here is what I finally was able to do after combining several sources:

```
\author{Name Someone, Name Elsewise, Name Again-Again, Name (Nickname) Last, Name B. Fine\textsuperscript{a}, Name Additional\textsuperscript{a},
  Name Other\textsuperscript{b}, and Name Capper\textsuperscript{c}\\
  \vspace{1mm}
  \begin{flushleft}
  \footnotesize\textsuperscript{a}Department of Something, University of State and City, City, ST\\
  \textsuperscript{b}Department of Some Sciences, University of State and City, City, ST\\
  \textsuperscript{c}Department of Another Thing, University of State and City, City, ST
  \end{flushleft}
```

}[image]