# help redefining \maketitle and use of \thanks

Tags: titles

I needed to change the title page so that the title and authors were flushed left. For that I found some code in the answer here: [Left align abstract, title and authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85343/left-align-abstract-title-and-authors).

But I still have a few problems:
1. remove the space between the authors and the addresses.
2. my call to \thanks doesn't work any more.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk} %affiliations
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %justify

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
      \textbf{\@title} \\[24pt]

      \@author
    \end{flushleft}\egroup
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \title{\huge {My Title}}

    \author[a]{Author1}\thanks{Corresponding author email:email@so.so}
    \author[b,c]{author2}

    \affil[a]{\small{\textit{address1}}}
    \affil[b]{\small{\textit{address2}}}

    \maketitle
    \justify

    \noindent
    \textbf{Abstract.} My abstract goes here. \\

    \noindent Keywords: a few words here.

    \section{Introduction} 
    Text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `authblk` works with its own version of `\maketitle`; if you redefine `\maketitle`…

Comment: You know, you really don't need to use \maketitle at all.  Just format the title page as any other.  Commands are supposed to make things easier, not harder.

Comment: I tried to do my own title page and it did not came out right. This was the closest I got to the right format but maybe I need to go back to making my own title page and give it another try.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should complete the coding by copying the way `authblk` modifies the `\maketitle` command: it saves a copy in `\AB@maketitle` and then redefines the `tabular` environment.  In `authblk` the code is

```
\let\AB@maketitle=\maketitle
\def\maketitle
  {{\renewenvironment{tabular}[2][]{\begin{center}}
                                   {\end{center}}
  \AB@maketitle}}
```

You just want to change that `center` environment to a `flushleft`.

Secondly for the vertical spacing, `authblk` has the length `\affilsep` which by default is `1em`.  You can make it zero by writing

```
\setlength{\affilsep}{0pt}
```

Thirdly, `\thanks` can be replaced by `\footnote` without problem.

Now for some style comments.  Setting of font sizes etc. should be done in your macro definitions etc. not added to the final text.  So for the new `\maketitle` command write

```
{\huge\textbf{\@title}\par}
```

to get a huge bold title.  (You can follow the `\par` by `\vspace{...}` to add some vertical space here.)  Similarly styling of the affiliations and small italic should be set via `authblk`'s mechanism of specifying the `\Affilfont`:

```
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\itshape\small}
```

Putting this together gives

[image: Sample output]

with a corresponding author note at the bottom of the page:

[image: Sample foot]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\setlength{\affilsep}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\itshape\small}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  {\huge\textbf{\@title}\par}

  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\let\AB@maketitle=\maketitle
\def\maketitle{{\renewenvironment{tabular}[2][]{\begin{flushleft}}
  {\end{flushleft}}
  \AB@maketitle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\author[a]{Author One\footnote{Corresponding author email email@so.so}}
\author[b,c]{Author Two}

\affil[a]{Address one\newline Town\newline Country}
\affil[b]{Address two\newline Town\newline Country}

\maketitle

\noindent
\textbf{Abstract.} My abstract goes here. 

\smallskip

\noindent Keywords: a few words here.

\section{Introduction} 
Text.

\end{document}
```