# Error while trying to left align the author section

Tags: errors, positioning

I would like to left align the `\author` section in an article without using the `memoir`-package so that it looks like this:

```
Author1 name          Author2 name
Author1 mail          Author2 mail

Author3 name          Author4 name
Author3 mail          Author4 mail

Author5 name          Author6 name
Author5 mail          Author6 mail
```

I've tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titling}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{\@title}

  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\author{ 
Author 1 \\
{\normalsize \href{mailto:author1@domain.com}{\texttt{author1@domain.com}}}\\

\and

Author 2 \\
{\normalsize \href{mailto:author2@domain.com}{\texttt{author2@domain.com}}}\\

\and

Author 3 \\
{\normalsize \href{mailto:author3@domain.com}{\texttt{author3@domain.com}}}\\

\and

Author 4 \\
{\normalsize \href{mailto:author4@domain.com}{\texttt{author4@domain.com}}}\\

\and

Author 5 \\
{\normalsize \href{mailto:author5@domain.com}{\texttt{author5@domain.com}}}\\

\and

Author 6 \\
{\normalsize \href{mailto:author6@domain.com}{\texttt{author6@domain.com}}}\\

}


\title{The Title}
\date{}



\maketitle

text text text text text text  text text text text text text

\end{dokument}
```

as this post suggest [Left align abstract, title and authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85343/left-align-abstract-title-and-authors)

but I get the error:

```
! Misplaced \crcr.\endarray ->\crcr\egroup \egroup \gdef \@preamble {}\CT@end
```

Can anyone tell me why I get this error and what I should do to correct it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I try in a standard setup (article class) there is no error!

Comment: Could you leave some feedback about the answers here, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushleft}}
\predate{\begin{flushleft}}
\postdate{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `tabular`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
  \Large\textbf{\@title}\\[2ex]
  \large \@author \\[2ex]
  \@date \\[1.5em]
\end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\title{Some title}
\author{%
Author
}

\pagestyle{empty} % disables page numbers

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. A post elsewhere on the forum re graphicx provides the answer - you are using \and within the \author block. That is the immediate cause of the error.

See [misplaced crcr when using graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410446/misplaced-crcr-when-using-graphicx)! for more information how to form a solution to your needs.

Since I went to a left-justified single column author block, replacing \and with
...\\
~\\
generated a sufficient blank line between authors

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post link-only answers, but explicitly adapt the information of the linked post to the current case.