# Misplaced \crcr. when using graphicx

Tags: graphics, titles, logos

I'm trying to change the maketitle command in order to add a logo over the title. When importing the package graphicx I'm getting the following error :

```
! Misplaced \crcr.
\endarray ->\crcr 
              \egroup \egroup \@arrayright \gdef \@preamble {}
l.29     \maketitle
```

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{CatCatch\\Cahier des charges}
\author{Several Authors}
\date{19 janvier 2018}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=120mm]{logo.png}\\[8ex]
        {\Huge \@title }\\[4ex] 
        {\Large \@author}\\[4ex] 
        \@date\\[8ex]
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, make a minimal example that produces the error (probably you have more than one author with `\and` between them).

Answer (score 4):

The error only appears if you separate author names by `\and`.

You should redefine `\and` to do something meaningful with your redefinition of `\@maketitle`: the default definition doesn't.

Note the small changes I made: the `\\` should be inside the scope of the font size changing commands, or the spacing would be wrong.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{CatCatch\\Cahier des charges}
\author{A. Uthor \and W. Riter}
\date{19 janvier 2018}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\and}{\\}
\def\@maketitle{%
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=120mm]{example-image}\\[8ex]
        {\Huge \@title\\[4ex]}
        {\Large \@author\\[4ex]}
        \@date\\[8ex]
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

I used `example-image` instead of `logo`, just in order to typeset something visible.

[image]

Comment: I did what you said, but the logo doesn't show up anyway.
Is it because I use `\bsc` in the author tag ?
Also, I'm using the argument `titlepage`in `\documentclass`

Comment: @MarcSchmitt Sorry, but it’s impossible to give advice about code you don’t show.

Comment: Sorry I'm having a huge headache. When I get back at my computer, I'll upload the whole thing

Comment: Here, I modified my question with the new code

Comment: @MarcSchmitt You shouldn't change the question so as to invalidate the answer, so I rolled back the change. Anyway, I have no problem with the image. Please, open a new question for the different problem.

Comment: I have the same error. What is the problem with the `\and` command? In other answers on this site you are recommended to use it.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist The problem is with the standard definition of `\and`; if you want it to do something different, you have to modify it.