# Left align abstract, title and authors in amsart class

Tags: align, titles, amsart

I would like to re-align my title, authors and their addresses to the left of the document in `amsart` class. I found an example, but it did not work.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno,english]{amsart}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
    \usepackage[]{lipsum}

\newcommand{\blankbox}[2]{%
  \parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fbox{\raisebox{0pt}[#2]{\hspace{#1}}}}} 
  \setcounter{page}{1}


\setlength{\columnsep}{0.7cm} 
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt plus1pt minus1pt} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}


\begin{document}



\title[Title of the manuscript goes here]{\textbf{Title of the manuscript goes here}}
\author[Author1, Author2]{Author1$^a$ \and Author2$^b$ \vspace{0.58cm}
\\ \small
$^a$Department of Industrial Engineering, \\
author1@mmmm.edu \vspace{0.1cm} \\
$^b$Department of Mathematics\\
author2@mmmm.edu \vspace{0.4cm} \\
\textit{(Received: $\mathit{18}$ March $\mathit{2011}$; Accepted: $\mathit{8}$ July $\mathit{2011}$; Available Online: $\mathit{30}$ August $\mathit{2011}$})}

\thanks{E-mail addresses. mmmmmmmm}


\begin{abstract}


\lipsum[1]

\vspace{7pt}
\noindent
\textbf{Keywords: }{First keyword; second keyword; ... ; fifth keyword}

\vspace{2pt}
\noindent
\textbf{AMS Classification:} Find your AMS Code from \url{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[3]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

I found some command for the article class [command for article.cls](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85343/left-align-abstract-title-and-authors)

Comment: A very warm welcome here at tex.stackexchange.com. You don't need to post "Hi" and "Thank you". In fact, we prefer if you don't, in order to keep the posts simple an clean.  Maybe you can explain a bit more what is not working, so that we can understand you problem without having to compile your code.

Comment: When I paste the code in example, the title align left. But the author name and addresses disappeared .

Comment: `\begin{multicols}` ended with  `\end{multicols*}`  (`*`), that need to be corrected first.

Comment: I found related part (title and author) in amsart.cls file. And replace centering etc. command with flushleft. It is work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of changing `center` for the title into `flushleft` and `\centering` for the author field into `\raggedright`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno,english]{amsart}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx,url,etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@settitle}{center}{flushleft}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@settitle}{center}{flushleft}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setauthors}{\centering}{\raggedright}{}{}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{3pc}{0pt}{}{} % remove indentation
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title of the manuscript goes here}
\author[Author1, Author2]{Author1$^a$ \and Author2$^b$ \vspace{0.58cm}
\\ \small
$^a$Department of Industrial Engineering, \\
author1@mmmm.edu \vspace{0.1cm} \\
$^b$Department of Mathematics\\
author2@mmmm.edu \vspace{0.4cm} \\
\textit{(Received: 18 March 2011; 
  Accepted: 8 July 2011;
  Available Online: 30 August 2011})}

\thanks{E-mail addresses. mmmmmmmm}


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\keywords{First keyword; second keyword; ... ; fifth keyword}
\subjclass{Find your AMS Code from \url{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html}}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that `$\mathit{18}$` is not necessary: those are not numbers in their arithmetical sense, but just words.